# can I freeze chicken defrost it and eat cold for lunch?

Tags: freezing

Recently, I have started to eat healthy and got into bodybuilding. I see a lot of videos of people cooking in bulk for the week online; this would save time for me as I'm very busy in college and work. I was just wondering if I could freeze meats such as steak and chicken then take them out of the freezer and eat them cold when defrosted? I would like to have them to eat on the go.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's perfectly fine, assuming the meats were cooked properly originally. If you look up people doing bento lunches, they use freezer staples a lot; often, if the item is small enough, it can be packed in a lunch still frozen and be defrosted by lunchtime. However, if you're talking about a whole steak or chicken breast, you'll want to stick it in the fridge overnight to let it defrost first.

Comment: Thanks for responding and yeah am cooking the likes of chicken breast and a few pieces of steak and thanks for the advice much appreciated